# How to check ios wifi, LTE, 3G network check

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

```
etworkStatus netStatus = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus];
    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    NSString* statusString= @"";
// LTE Check
    if([networkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]){ 
        statusString = @"LTE";
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:[OTPAppDelegate getAppTitle]
                                  message: statusString
                                  delegate: self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:CONFIRM otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alertView show];
        return YES;
    }        

    // network check
    switch (netStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable: 
        {
            statusString = NETWORK_ERROR;
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                      initWithTitle:[OTPAppDelegate getAppTitle]
                                      message: statusString
                                      delegate: self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:CONFIRM otherButtonTitles: nil];

            [alertView show];
            return YES;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            //            statusString = @"GRPS/3G Connect.";
            return NO;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            //            statusString= @"WiFi Connect.";
            statusString = WIFI_CHECK;
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                      initWithTitle:[OTPAppDelegate getAppTitle]
                                      message: statusString
                                      delegate: self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:CONFIRM otherButtonTitles: nil];

            [alertView show];
            return YES;
            break;
        }                
    }
    return NO;        
}
```

i try that source. But Fail

in iOS simulator, networkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology Value is Not LTE

but in real iOS device,

networkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology Value is always LTE.

How to Check LTE connect in iOS?

Comment: Be more clear about 'is not' and 'is always' LTE.

Comment: if i try in Wifi Network Connection in real iOS device, So 'if([networkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE])' Value is True